# Bullet spawn error CS1061: Transform does not contain a definition for 'Position'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello my problem here is that i try to make a bulletprefab spawm from a game object but this *error CS1061:

> 'Transform' does not contain a definition for 'Position' and no
>   accessible extension method 'Position' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'Transform' could be found*.

Dont let me do that. Here's the code **lanzador is the spawner and balaprefab is the bulletprefab**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CtrlJugador : MonoBehaviour
{
    public  Rigidbody balaprefab;
    public  Transform Lanzador;
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
            Instantiate(balaprefab, Lanzador.Position, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: C# identifiers are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Trust the error message!  The compiler is telling you that `myTransform.Position` doesn't exist, which means that it doesn't exist.  I did a quick google search, and found this:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html

That attribute is what you're looking for.  Note that the name `position` is all lower-case.

Comment: [Should we answer or comment on a typo question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174389/should-we-answer-or-comment-on-a-typo-question)

Answer (score 1):

One thing good to know: The fields in unity scripts are all named camelCase. No field starts with uppercase character.

What you wanted to access is `Transform.position`, not `Position`. Take care and trust the error message!

Comment: [Should we answer or comment on a typo question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174389/should-we-answer-or-comment-on-a-typo-question)